# Why isn't my pre-decrement on I working as I expected?

Tags: java

So I've been trying to solve fibonnacci iterative and I've found out that it doesn't seem to matter if the final clause of the for loop is --i or i-- what doesn't make any sense for me.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(fibo(5));
    }
    public static int fibo(int n){
        int fiboval=0;
        for (int i= n;i>(n-2);--i){
            if(i<=1){
                fiboval+=1;
            }else{
                fiboval=fiboval+i;
            }
        }
        return fiboval;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting?  What's the problem?

Comment: `I've been trying to solve fibonnacci recursively` - I see no recursion here.

Comment: @Eran yeah, I had done it previously recursively and worked fine and messed up with the names when asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not assigning the value of i to anything, or using it in a more complicated expression, --i and i-- will have the same effect.

For example...

Post-increment...

```
int i = 10;
int n = i++; // After this statement, i will be 11 and n will be 10.
```

Pre-increment...

```
int i = 10;
int n = ++i; // After this statement, i will be 11 and n will be 11.
```

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of the operators is as follows

- `--i` evaluates to `(i-1)` and then sets `i=i-1`
- `i--` evaluates to `i` and then sets `i=i-1`

The only difference is in what the expression evaluates to. They both effectively set `i` to a new value. And the next time `i` is referenced the new value will be seen.

In order to see the difference between the two variants you have to make use of the value the expression evaluates to.

For example:

- `int x = i--`
- `int x = --i`
- `myArray[i--]`
- `myArray[--i]`

In the above examples `x` will have different values and a different element will be referenced in `myArray`.

Answer (score 0):

In the increment/decrement clause of a for loop post-decrement and pre-decrement operators will result with the same outcome, since the next time the loop's condition is tested, it will see the decremented value either way.

There would be a difference only if the value of `i--` or `--i` is used immediately.

For example:

```
if (i-- > (n-2))
```

and

```
if (--i > (n-2))
```

will compare different values to `n-2`.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected, but it does not make a difference in the way you are using it...
The so-called postfix operator only makes sense if you are using it in the same line.
But the loop is calling the increment/decrement at the end and then checking in a seperate statement if the condition is still true